# Valgrind port for PowerPC/QNX

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, powerpc, qnx-neutrino

I'm looking for a suitable tool for tackling memory leaks on a PowerPC/QNX system. QNX uses some tools but it is clunky and almost useless to track memory leaks. I had used Valgrind on a different system (ARM/Linux) before and had very good results with it. Wondering if you have heard of a Valgrind port for PPC/QNX?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same tool. Any updates?